# How to retrieve the raw output data from my NMDS graph?

Tags: r, vegan

I have run an NMDS analysis with the vegan package and produced the graph below. I would now like to extract the values (x value from the NMDS 1 axis and y value from NMDS 2 axis) of each of the points within the graph. I have done some searching around online but haven't found any solutions. Has anyone done this before?

The data is organized as a dataframe with 4 columns, one for each Arctic habitat in the graph, and 208 rows, each row is the total count of a species in each Arctic habitat.

Here is the code I used to produce the graph:

```
library(vegan)

arctichabitat<-read.csv(file.choose())

arctichabitat.nmds <- metaMDS(arctichabitat, distance = "bray", trace = F, trymax = 100)

plot(arctichabitat.nmds)
text(arctichabitat.nmds, display = "species", csv = 0.5)
```

[image]

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All **vegan** ordination objects have function `scores` that can extract the values you asked. This is even documented: see `?metaMDS`.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by the `metaMDS` function has an attribute called `points` which has the values you are looking for:

```
nmds_coordinates <- arctichabitat.nmds$points
```

The data frame has two columns, `MDS1` and `MDS2`. I'm not sure why they are not called `NMDS1` and `NMDS2`, but I checked a couple data sets with

```
plot(arctichabitat.nmds$points)
```

and they appear to be the same values used for the default object graph you provided.

Comment: Using `scores()` is safer as the internal structure of objects is liable to change

Comment: this method also worked for me, but I will take the advice that scores() is safer. Thanks!